# How do I set the region or location for the Dialogflow C# SDK?

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

Dialogflow recently released the ability to create agents in specific regions.   But I'm having difficulty interacting with those agents using the C# libraries.

I'm working on doing a Dialogflow Restore in C# programmatically for a Dialogflow agent in another region.   Code similar to below works fine when I'm just using the default/standard Dialogflow region.   But when I try to set the endpoint to the australia-southeast1 endpoint an exception occurs that says I'm trying to access a resource in the US.    I'm trying with the Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 package v3.0.0.

What am I missing to set the region or location correctly?

```
var builder = new AgentsClientBuilder()
{
  JsonCredentials = "{ ... }",
  Endpoint = "australia-southeast1-dialogflow.googleapis.com:443"
};

var client = builder.Build();

var request = new RestoreAgentRequest
{
  ParentAsProjectName = new Google.Api.Gax.ResourceNames.ProjectName("test-au-project-id-xsgt"),
  AgentUri = "gs://bucketname/filename.zip"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Regions doesn't work yet when integrating from your own code.

The agents currently have to be created in the default region (in America).

If you delete your existing agent and create a new one from the code, it will be created in the default reqion.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are stuck with this problem on nodejs, the resolution is quite simple - suppose the region is a parameter ([available regions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region#regions)):

```
const region = 'europe-west1';
const df = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow').v2;
const dfClient = region === 'global' ? new df.IntentsClient() : new df.IntentsClient({ apiEndpoint: `${region}-dialogflow.googleapis.com` });
const projectAgentPath = region === 'global' ? dfClient.projectAgentPath(projectId) : dfClient.projectLocationAgentPath(projectId, region);
```

[Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region#api) instructs to specify the port (443), but it must be obsolete, since when the port is set you will get a Permission denied.

For every DF request, pass the projectAgentPath

```
async function listIntents(handler) {
    const request = {
        parent: projectAgentPath,
    };

    // Send the request for listing intents.
    const [response] = await dfClient.listIntents(request);
    handler(response);
}
```